# MySQL : How to perform multiple calculations and group by two columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm very new to MySql and so this may be a silly question. Did some research and have been cracking at it for hours, but still am stuck.

So I have a table that contains the following columns (about 100,000 rows).

1. IP Address Range
2. City
3. State
4. Customer_ID

I want to create a new table that has

1. IP Address Range.
2. City
3. State
4. Number of times each city/state combination occurs per IP Address range
5. Total number of city/state combinations per IP address range
6. Frequency of each city/state combination in range (so basically column 4 divided by five).

I can get it to show 1,2,3 and 5. But I can't get seem to create a query that will show column 4 based on each city/state combination.

Do I need to create multiple tables or use a subselect?

Once again I'm new at this, so apologies if this is an easy question!

Comment: Start simple and build your way up.  Can you select the address range and the number of times each one occurs?

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure that I get your question. your can try this
SELECT max(ip), state, city, MAX(customerid), count(ip) FROM `stack2` group by state, city

Comment: you can do calculation in same query